# Compare base class part of sub class instance to another base class instance

Tags: c#

I have number of [DTO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) classes in a system. They are organized in an inheritance hierarchy.

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string ListName { get; set; }
}

class PersonDetailed : Person
{
    public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    public byte[] Image { get; set; }
}
```

The reason for splitting it up is to be able to get a list of people for e.g. search results, without having to drag the heavy image and phone numbers along. Then the full `PersonDetail` DTO is loaded when the details for one person is selected.

The problem I have run into is comparing these when writing unit tests. Assume I have

```
Person p1 = myService.GetAPerson();
PersonDetailed p2 = myService.GetAPersonDetailed();

// How do I compare the base class part of p2 to p1?
Assert.AreEqual(p1, p2);
```

The `Assert` above will fail, as `p1` and `p2` are different classes. Is it possible to somehow only compare the base class part of `p2` to `p1`? Should I implement `IEquatable<>` on `Person`? Other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit more investigation (based on LBushkin's answer) made me change my mind.

`Assert.Equals` calls the `Equals` method to compare the object. In my case I could have created an override on `Person` that would accept any type that can be casted to a `Person` and then compares all the attributes. This would make my original code work:

```
Assert.AreEqual(p1, p2);
```

I would also have to override Equals in my `PersonExtended` class to check the extra fields present. However that would have "funny" consequences:

```
Assert.AreEqual(p1, p2); // calls p1.Equals(p2) - evaluates to true.
Assert.AreEqual(p2, p1); // calls p2.Equals(p1) - evaluates to false.
```

At this point I decided to build something more simple - the result was an extension method on the `Person` type that compares. This has some advantages:

- Can handle a `null` left-hand argument.
- It is non-virtual - it is clear that the declared type of the variable is the comparison 
  used.

Now all appeared to be well and I could continue coding. Until I found out that the entire idea of having inheritance between the basic and extended DTOs is flawed. I thought that the `DataContractSerializer` that WCF uses would serialize the type that the parameter of the function was declared as. It doesn't. It serializes the object's actual type. That means that if a `PersonExtended` object is passed to a method that only requires a `Person` the entire extended method is transferred over the wire anyways, so it's better to stick with simple composition.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that `Assert.AreEqual` calls the `Equals` method on the instances involved. You should be able to simply override the Equals logic and check to see at runtime whether you are comparing one of the possible cases:

- Person <-> Person
- Person <-> PersonDetailed
- PersonDetailed <-> Person  or
- PersonDetailed <-> PersonDetailed

You can them implement the appropriate logic for each case, or delegate to an external comparer as you see fit. I don't know off-hand if any unit testing frameworks other than Microsofts support checking for `IEquatable<T>` when you ask them to verify equality.